# Appending SQL data into datatables using JAVA in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

In my SQL Server I have the following result sets after all the condition filtering and sum query execution.

[image: SQL Results]

I would like to be shown like this in my page (refer to the screenshot below).

[image: ![Actual Results Needed]

I have tried the below JAVA code that gave me the results that I appended into my datatables.

```
<%
ArrayList<String[]> rows = sqlq.querySQL();
String rowsetdate = new String();
String rowres1 = new String();
    for(String[] rowset : rows) { 
      rowsetdate = rowset[0];
      rowres1 = rowres1 + rowset[1]+ ",";
        for(String rowres2 : rowset) {
        rowres1 = rowres1 + rowres2 + ",";
         }
      rowres1 = rowres1.substring(0, rowres1.length()-1);
      rowres1 = rowres1 + "|";
     }
rowres1 = rowres1.substring(0, rowres1.length()-1);
%>

<tr>
<td><%if (rowres1  == null) out.print(""); else out.print(rowres1);%></td>
</tr>
```

`sqlq.querySQL()` is used to send my SQL query to JDBC in order for me to send query to my DB.

Photo below is the appended data in my datatables after the code execution, on the left is the Date and on the right is the data.

[image: Sets of Data]

I tried some different code,

```
<%
ArrayList<String[]> rows = sqlq.querySQL();
 for(String[] rowset : rows) {
<tr>
<td><%if (rowset[0]  == null) out.print(""); else out.print(rowset[0]);%></td>
<td><%if (rowset[1]  == null) out.print(""); else out.print(rowset[1]);%></td>
</tr>
}
%>
```

which did not achieve my expected results also, it returns the data like how I see it in my SSMS (check screenshot below)

[image: wrong sql]

What did I do wrong and how should I do it to get my expected outcome? (screenshot below)

[image: expected outcome]

Appreciate the help from all of you.

Comment: Why not use a window function to calculate this in SQL? See [`OVER` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @KarolDowbecki i think this is something i has to be changed on my java code? Anyway i will give Over clause a try too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Map that its key is `date` and its value again is a Map. Inner Map uses `trans` as key and `sumtot` as value.

```java
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapByDate = new HashMap<>();
    TreeSet<String> allTrans = new TreeSet<>();

    for (String[] row : rows) {
      Map<String, String> mapByDateAndTrans = mapByDate.get(row[0]);
      if (mapByDateAndTrans == null) {
        mapByDateAndTrans = new HashMap<>();
      }
      mapByDateAndTrans.put(row[1], row[2]);
      mapByDate.put(row[0], mapByDateAndTrans);
      allTrans.add(row[1]);
    }
```

Here is a sample code to print data as you might expect:

```
    System.out.println("Date/Trans: " + allTrans);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> mapByDateEntry : mapByDate.entrySet()) {
      System.out.print(mapByDateEntry.getKey() + ": ");
      Map<String, String> mapByTrans = mapByDateEntry.getValue();
      for (String trans : allTrans) {
        String sumtot = mapByTrans.get(trans);
        if (sumtot != null) {
          System.out.print("[ " + sumtot + " ]");
        } else {
          System.out.print("[   ]");
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
```

The output:

```
Date/Trans: [11200, 11201, 11202]
2019-07-02: [ 136 ][ 18 ][ 14 ]
2019-07-03: [ 164 ][ 10 ][ 8 ]
```

Or we can generate an HTML table content:

```
    StringBuilder tableBuilder = new StringBuilder("<table border = 1>");
    // table header
    tableBuilder.append("<tr>");
    tableBuilder.append("<th>date/trans</th>");
    for (String trans : allTrans) {
      tableBuilder.append("<th>").append(trans).append("</th>");
    }
    tableBuilder.append("</tr>");

    // table rows
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> mapByDateEntry : mapByDate.entrySet()) {
      tableBuilder.append("<tr>");
      tableBuilder.append("<td>").append(mapByDateEntry.getKey()).append("</td>");
      Map<String, String> mapByTrans = mapByDateEntry.getValue();
      for (String trans : allTrans) {
        String sumtot = mapByTrans.get(trans);
        if (sumtot != null) {
          tableBuilder.append("<td>").append(sumtot).append("</td>");
        } else {
          tableBuilder.append("<td></td>");
        }
      }
      tableBuilder.append("<tr>");
    }
    tableBuilder.append("</table>");

    System.out.println(tableBuilder.toString());
```

The Output:

```
<table border = 1><tr><th>date/trans</th><th>11200</th><th>11201</th><th>11202</th></tr><tr><td>2019-07-02</td><td>136</td><td>18</td><td>14</td><tr><tr><td>2019-07-03</td><td>164</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><tr></table>
```

If we save generated output as an HTML file, It maybe your desired result (screenshot below). Also you can change the code to be used in JSP:

[image]

To have an ordered Map by natural order of its keys, a `TreeMap` can be used. So to print the data ordered by date, we can construct a new TreeMap containing the `mapByDate` data:

```
    TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>> sortedMapByDate = new TreeMap<>(mapByDate);
    // table rows
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> mapByDateEntry : sortedMapByDate.entrySet()) {
      tableBuilder.append("<tr>");
      tableBuilder.append("<td>").append(mapByDateEntry.getKey()).append("</td>");
      Map<String, String> mapByTrans = mapByDateEntry.getValue();
      for (String trans : allTrans) {
        String sumtot = mapByTrans.get(trans);
        if (sumtot != null) {
          tableBuilder.append("<td>").append(sumtot).append("</td>");
        } else {
          tableBuilder.append("<td></td>");
        }
      }
      tableBuilder.append("<tr>");
    }
```

Comment: This is not working either, i am constantly getting errors on my code when running.

Comment: @Mohen I am getting multiple errors.

1. The method sorted(Comparator<? super Object>) in the type Stream<Object> is not applicable for the arguments (String::compareTo)

2. The type String does not define compareTo(Object, Object) that is applicable here

All related to this line and after,

mapByDate.put(row[0], mapByDateAndTrans);}.........................

Comment: @justarandom, I've updated the code by replaced List with TreeSet to have sorted trans. Please let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: Its working, but when i try to put it in my datatables, it shows the data line by line instead of column like how it is in my screenshot provided above in my question, check my question for updated code.

Comment: @justarandom Sorry, I'm not sure I understood what you mean. Maybe because of my poor English :( I'll update the code, hope to be the solution

Comment: Yeah the updated code may actually solve the problem, but then it is creating a new table to show the results, what i actually want is to append the results into my existing table without appending the .append(<td>) tags, is that even possible?

Comment: @justarandom yes :)

Comment: It is working, but when i query multiple data from my SQL, the date  is not sorting according to Ascending order, how to i make it to sort by ascending?

Comment: @justarandom A `TreeMap` can be used to have an ordered Map according to the natural ordering of its keys. Use the below line befor printing table rows and `sortedMapByDate` instead of `mapByDate` in printing for block:
`TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>> sortedMapByDate = new TreeMap<>(mapByDate);`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!! @Mohsen Zamani This solve my problems!

Comment: yw ;-) 

There are some other ways to do this. for example when you are grouping data by date and time or when you want to use a different ordering method and the others.
```JAVA
Map<String, Map<String, List<String[]>>> groupedByDateAndTrans = rows.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o[0], Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o[1])));
```

Comment: Right, i will give it a try whenever if i need it! Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's wasteful to do this in Java code, that's what the window functions are for in SQL. If you have a query like `SELECT datet, trans, sumtout FROM ...` you can use `SUM` with [`OVER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT datet, SUM(sumtout) OVER (PARTITION BY datet)
FROM ...
ORDER BY datet;
```

Comment: This is not working, SQL is giving me other SUM values.